# checking the database value using sugarRecord

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sugarorm

i am having a problem in checking the value passed by the user every time,is already there in the sugarORM database. I am using this line of code to retrieve the value.but this line of doesn't get execute

```
private void postDataToSQLite() {



        User.find(User.class, "email = ? and password = ?", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim(),textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: write more code and make more detailed your question. What does mean "not executing", it throws error or just not executing?

Comment: i have added my entire method.i want to check whether the user is existing in the data base.but when i execute the code,it displays member is already registered.may i know where i am making the mistake

Comment: for loop doesnt work .may i know where the error is?

Comment: Try turning on `QUERY_LOG` [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html), and ensure the resulting SQL matches your expectations.